# configure iis to redirect to domain with 200 status code

Tags: redirect, iis-7

I have old version of site on IIS server. `MyDomain1.com` is binded to that iis server. I created new version of this site on node.js and want slowly to move on it. But if I rebind `MyDomain1.com` to new node.js server and something is going wrong on new version of site I have to rollback to iis. Rebinding domain is slow - about 4 houres. Can I simply redirect `MyDomain1.com` to `MyDomain2.com` which is allready binded to node.js server. I don't want `301` redirect. I want status code `200` and  seamless redirection to another domain with appropriate path of all requests to `MyDomain1.com`. Is it possible?

For example if I have requrest to url `http://MyDomain1.com/get/item/323` I want to redirect to url `http://MyDomain2.com/get/item/323` with status code `200`.

Comment: Status code 200 means "OK". It doesn't mean "redirect". It is the 300 codes that _cause_ redirection. There's no way to redirect without them. What you're asking doesn't really make any sense. Are you sure you mean "redirect"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only rewrite,

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

or route the request,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.90).aspx

Redirect is always 30*, and that's determined by HTTP standard.